# Trying to save an animation gives error: OSError: Error saving animation to file (cause: [Errno 22] Invalid argument)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I am trying to save an animation, but I get the error:

OSError: Error saving animation to file (cause: [Errno 22] Invalid argument) Stdout: b'' StdError: b''. It may help to re-run with logging level set to DEBUG.

I have installed ffmpeg and also added the path to it in my code. If I add `print(animation.writers.list())`, it gives 'ffmpeg' in the list as well so I'm sure my computer can find the right file.

At the top of my code, I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
```

And when saving the animation, I have:

```
SubplotAnimation_1 = SubplotAnimation(F_vector, eta_atm, Pkid, Tb_sky)
Writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), extra_args=['--verbose-debug'])
file_string = r'C:/Users/Esmee/Documents/Animations/animation_tryout.mp4'
print(file_string)
SubplotAnimation_1.save(file_string, writer=Writer)
```

I have added the `r` in front of the string, so there are no problems with the `/a` in the file_string. The folder C:/Users/Esmee/Documents/Animations/ exists for sure, so that also shouldn't be a problem. 
I have also tried

```
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
mywriter = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
```

But it doesn't work either.

I have looked at [animation save gets errror](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2764), [How can I overcome this key word error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032543/how-can-i-overcome-this-key-word-error) and [No Moviewriters available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736457/runtimeerror-no-moviewriters-available-in-matplotlib-animation), but none of them offers a solution to my problem.

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the code below worked:

```
Writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'))
file_string = r'C:/Users/Esmee/Documents/Animations/animation_tryout.mp4'
SubplotAnimation_1.save(file_string, writer=Writer)
```

I think the argument `extra_args=['--verbose-debug']` (that I got from another solution to this problem) in the `animation.FFMpegWriter` command was causing  the program to crash. I didn't change anything in the import statements on the top of the program.

I hope this post serves to help anyone with a similar problem!